# ASP.NET MVC , LINQ : calculate date difference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to filter my records with different parameters. But I get an exception when I have to filter records for the items that would expire within 30, 60 or 90 days.

Here is my code:

```
 public IQueryable<Stock> FilterStocks(StockSearchVM searchModel)
    {
        var result = db.Stocks.AsQueryable();
        if (searchModel != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchModel.batch))
                result = result.Where(x => x.BatchNo == searchModel.batch);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.name))
                result = result.Where(x => x.Item.Name.Contains(searchModel.name));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.option))
            {
                if (searchModel.option == "BelowMin")
                {
                    result = result.Where(x => x.Qty < x.Item.AlertQty);
                }
                else if (searchModel.option == "UnSold")
                {
                    result = result.Where(x => x.Qty == x.InitialQty);
                }

                else if(searchModel.option == "90")
                {
                    result = result.Where(x => ( Convert.ToDateTime(x.ExpiryDate) - DateTime.Now).Days < 90);
                }
                else if (searchModel.option == "60")
                {
                    result = result.Where(x => (Convert.ToDateTime(x.ExpiryDate) - DateTime.Now).Days < 60);
                }
                else if (searchModel.option == "30")
                {
                    result = result.Where(x => (Convert.ToDateTime(x.ExpiryDate) - DateTime.Now).Days < 30);
                }
                else if (searchModel.option == "15")
                {
                    result = result.Where(x => (Convert.ToDateTime(x.ExpiryDate) - DateTime.Now).Days < 15);
                }
                else if (searchModel.option == "Expired")
                {
                    result = result.Where(x => (Convert.ToDateTime(x.ExpiryDate) - DateTime.Now).Days < 0);
                }
            }
            if ((searchModel.fromDate != null) || (searchModel.toDate != null))
            {
                if (searchModel.fromDate != null && searchModel.toDate == null)
                {
                    result = result.Where(x => x.ExpiryDate > searchModel.fromDate);
                }
                if (searchModel.toDate != null && searchModel.fromDate == null)
                {
                    result = result.Where(x => x.ExpiryDate < searchModel.toDate);
                }
                if (searchModel.toDate != null && searchModel.fromDate != null)
                {
                    result = result.Where(x => (x.ExpiryDate > searchModel.fromDate && x.ExpiryDate < searchModel.toDate));
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and the **exception** I get :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   ToDateTime(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

**User Interface:** 
[image]

I also tried to use :**EntityFunctions.DiffDays** but this too didn't work.

```
result = result.Where(x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(Convert.ToDateTime(x.ExpiryDate), DateTime.Now) < 60);
```

Please, help me out with this.

Comment: What is the data type of `x.ExpiryDate`? If it's not a datetime type, then fix that so you don't need to convert.

Comment: Why are you using `Convert.ToDateTime()` if the property is already a `DateTime`?

Comment: What is the type of ExpiryDate? When you are using LINQ to Entities bare in mind that it has to convert your code to the underlying platform

Comment: Expiry date is also of DateTime. but it is stored in format 2015-10-18 but DateTime.Now is in format : 18-Oct-15 10:21:51 AM. So doesnt that create problem?? Well I tried with removing Convert.toDatetime it still gave me an error.

Comment: They are both `DateTime` objects - it makes no difference how you chose to display them or in what format. It just needs to be `(x => x.ExpiryDate - DateTime.Now).Days` but if that throwing an error, then you need to materialize your query - var result = db.Stocks.ToList();` (not .`AsQueryable()`)